# Need help switching to different GRUB bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I have two SSDs:

SSD1

- Windows 11
- Ubuntu 22.04

SSD2

- Ubuntu 22.04

I'd been using dual-boot on SSD1 until recently when I decided to buy Ubuntu it's own drive (SSD2, fresh install). The goal is to delete the Ubuntu partition on SSD1 entirely so Windows and Ubuntu have their own drives. My problem is my system boots using the GRUB bootloader on SSD1 Ubuntu.

Question: how can I (safely) change it so that my system boots using SSD2 Ubuntu's GRUB bootloader? i.e. switch which bootloader is being used, where after I can hopefully remove the SSD1 Ubuntu partition without any trouble.

Thanks in advance, hope that makes sense.

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your boot priority in your motherboard firmware settings. This process is not related to Ubuntu or any other operating system. If you're not sure how to change boot priority on your system, refer to the documentation and support for your motherboard.

Comment: @Nmath Ah yep, you're probably right. I thought it would've been along the lines of update-grub, grub-install etc, but your suggestion makes sense. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ubuntu's default install to any second internal or external drive is to use an ESP on first drive. You have to manually partition second drive with an ESP & reinstall grub, or leap thru several hoops to get installer to only see second drive. Old bug with various fixes posted. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Probably easiet, but not one I have used. Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator &